# Space used is proportional to $1/ε$. What does it mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

So I am reading algorithm analysis and I see the following "space used is proportional to $1/ε$". What does it mean? So we have universe of $n$ items, space used is proportional to $1/ε$... 
I am not really getting the idea! I Googled definition of proportional and I got the following:

> Given two variables $x$ and $y$, $y$ is directly proportional to $x$ ($x$ and $y$ vary directly, or $x$ and $y$ are in direct variation) if there is a non-zero constant $k$ such that $y = kx$

But I do not understand how to apply this to a sentence presented for algorithm analysis. 
I will be thankful for clarification!

Comment: Hard to say exactly without seeing the specifics, but my educated guess is that the algorithm has a parameter $\epsilon>0$ that the user can choose. Presumably it says something about the quality of the output. The closer to zero you pick $\epsilon$, the higher the quality. The case $\epsilon=0$ being the unattainable ideal. But the user needs to pay the price in terms of space needed by the algorithm. If you want to cut the distance from optimality by a factor of ten, you need ten times more memory to run the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Jyrki Lantonen already gave a good answer but I also want to note that given definition is perfectly applicable here, meaning: if you have space $S$ and it is proportional to a 1/$ε$ then it literally means that there exists some non-zero $k$ such that $S$ and $ε$ are connected in a particular way: $$S = k*1/ε$$